# FastCGI application - how to get the listening socket handle?

Tags: c++, sockets, assembly, fastcgi

All examples for the subject are based on some C/C++ libraries like fcgi_stdio and similar. But I want to make a FastCGI script, using assembly language and there is no such libraries.

Almost everything about the protocol and communication is clear, but I still can't understand how the program gets the handle to the listening socket, passed by the web server?

My findings:

I installed the lighttpd server and tried to configure it in order to get fastCGI to work with my programs.

But I was confused, that the configuration file needs "host" and "port" - Is this means the FastCGI should create the listening socket by itself? I mean using socket/bind/listen/accept functions? Then how my application will know these host and port parameters. They are in the web server config file?

The other way lighttpd allows is to specify some named socket path - for example "/tmp/myapp.socket". How my application have to handle this? And how it will know this path?

I tried to make some small program using accept(0, ...) as @user58697 specified in his answer (and this answer is in accordance with the official FastCGI specification!) Unfortunately nothing happened - the call to accept fails miserably!

So, is the communication is server specific?

Comment: I would guess that there would be at least one open-source implementation, that you could use as reference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Digging in tons of C source code in order to understand something that is probably very simple is not a good idea IMHO.

Comment: I haven't looked at it very much, but to me it seems like normal socket communication, meaning whenever the fcgi server receives a connection from the web server, the standard [accept()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/accept) call will return a new socket.

Comment: @Jester Yes, but the initial listening socket (the socket on which I have to execute accept()) is created by the web server and then is passed to the fastCGI script.

Comment: No it isn't. The fcgi server creates it, and the web server has to be configured to use it.

Comment: @Jester - I think you are wrong, but even if this is the case, then remains the question about the parameters of the connection the FastCGI script to create - IP address and port number - they have to be passed by the web server.

Comment: They are not. They are configured separately on both ends. At least all of the fcgi stuff I have looked at works like that.

Comment: @Jester - Why not to post your opinion in more details as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/22), from the application point of view FCGI_LISTENSOCK_FILENO equals to STDIN_FILENO, which is defined as 0. That means that you shall `accept(STDIN_FILENO, ...)` or even `accept(0, ...)`.

Comment: It seems to not be so simple... I will edit the question in order to describe my findings...